# IF THAN or CASE Statement depending on current time in where clause

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, filter, case-statement

I am trying to create a script that runs at different times, and each time it has to be a different filter.

For example: First report is from 2pm yesterday to 7am current day.

Something like:

```
AND CASE
    WHEN  DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) + '7:00'
THEN   clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
AND  clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
ELSE 
END
```

But I get an error in the THEN part on the `>=` saying incorrect syntax near >.

That maybe due to having an expression in WHEN and as well as THEN because I think you can only have one or the other.

After this if its 2PM in the current day another report needs to run going back to 7AM current day to 2PM current day. Need some guidance as to how to go about accomplishing that logic.

Is a case statement possible and if so how would I code it? I am new to SQL and programming let me know if you need more info.

Query

```
SELECT Nai.clmNum AS Claim_Num, coverage, FirstName, LastName, payee,  checkNum, checkAmount, tranType, 
Act.State, Act.AccNum, clm.createDtTm
FROM    dbo.Financial(NOLOCK) AS clm, dbo.CLMs(NOLOCK) AS   Nai,dbo.Account_NIGHTLY(nolock) AS Act  
WHERE   coverage in ('Injury', 'Property Damage', 'Liability')
AND     checkNum IS NOT NULL
AND     clm.fldrID = Nai.fldrID
AND     tranType = 'payment'
AND     Act.State = 'MA'
AND     Nai.AccNum = Act.AccNum

CASE --IF its 7AM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between yesterday 2pm(14) to current day 7am(7)

--AND       clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
--AND       clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

CASE --If its 11AM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between current day 7am(7) to current day 11am(11)

--AND       clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 7,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
--AND       clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

CASE -- If its 2PM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between current day 11am(11) to current day 2pm(14)

--AND       clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 11,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
--AND       clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 14, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Added query and logic I want to achieve, this query will run on these time frames though a stored procedure scheduled to run. I want it to check the correct time and if its 7 am check if new financials have happened between the first time frame and send a report. If its 11 am do that filter instead.

Thanks

Abdul

Comment: Exactly, you can't have a logical expression in the THEN part of the CASE.  It has to return a value.

Comment: ... have multiple scripts? If you don't want to repeat some parts, you can always use views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually do not need to use a case statement here.  You can accomplish this using AND/OR...  Below is an untested example.  Please note that if this script is run at a time other than 7am, 11am, or 2pm it will return nothing.

```
SELECT Nai.clmNum AS Claim_Num, coverage, FirstName, LastName, payee,  checkNum, checkAmount, tranType, 
Act.State, Act.AccNum, clm.createDtTm
FROM    dbo.Financial(NOLOCK) AS clm, dbo.CLMs(NOLOCK) AS   Nai,dbo.Account_NIGHTLY(nolock) AS Act  
WHERE   coverage in ('Injury', 'Property Damage', 'Liability')
AND     checkNum IS NOT NULL
AND     clm.fldrID = Nai.fldrID
AND     tranType = 'payment'
AND     Act.State = 'MA'
AND     Nai.AccNum = Act.AccNum

AND     (
            --IF its 7AM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between yesterday 2pm(14) to current day 7am(7)
            (
                DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = 7
                AND clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 14,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
                AND clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
            )
            OR
            --If its 11AM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between current day 7am(7) to current day 11am(11)
            (
                DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = 11
                AND clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 7,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
                AND clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
            )
            OR
            -- If its 2PM send a report out filtered on createDtTm between current day 11am(11) to current day 2pm(14)
            (
                DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = 14
                AND clm.createDtTm >= DATEADD(HOUR, 11,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
                AND clm.createDtTm <= DATEADD(HOUR, 14, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
            )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, @Charlie. That seems to work but how can I incorporate the current days time, and to run a different filter depending on it. I do see now if a case statement is written more properly it doesn't have any issue. Is what I am trying to do even possible with a case statement?

Comment: @Abdul, what you are trying to do is possible, but its hard to determine the best way to handle it by only seeing the where clause.  Can you please update your question to include the full script that you are trying to run?

Comment: okay, @Charlie I have updated the question and included the script. And added more information below the script.

Comment: @Abdul, sorry for my slow response!  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie. I was able to do the same thing but I made it more flexible by creating a table and force inserting the first date as End time, and use that in a variable as start time and date. I also fill the current date time in another variable and use those two to filter based on what time the query is run, the table feeds the last date as the start time and it keeps updating with an insert query at the end.